# pthread Deferred Cancelation

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

My Expectation is, the thread must print integers from 0 to 99 and then only it should get canceled because the cancellation point is outside the loop, but here we can see thread cancels arbitrarily. Can somebody pls help me understand the behavior?   Whats the point of Deferred Cancellation and cancellation point if the thread still cancels arbitrarily.

```
void *r1(void *args)
{
pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, 0);
pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, 0);
char str[100];
for (int t = 0; t < 100; t++)
{
    printf("%d\n", t);
}
pthread_testcancel();
}

int main()
{

pthread_t t1;
void *t1_ret = NULL;
pthread_attr_t attr1;
pthread_attr_init(&attr1);
pthread_create(&t1, 0, r1, 0);
printf("Cancelling thread\n");
if (pthread_cancel(t1) == -1)
{
    perror("Failed to cancel thread\n");
    return 1;
}
printf("Thread cancelled and cleaned up successfully\n");
printf("Returning from main\n");
pthread_exit(0);
return 0;
}
output:

Cancelling thread
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
Thread cancelled and cleaned up successfully
Returning from main
```

Comment: [pthread_create manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html): "*The new thread terminates in one of the following ways: .. the main
         thread performs a return from main().  This causes the
         termination of all threads in the process.*".

Comment: even if I terminate the main thread with pthread_Exit(0), then also the same behavior. When the main thread terminates, then child threads continue to run. @kaylum. Updated the ques to include call to pthread_exit(0);

Comment: What do you mean by "child thread continue to run"? It obviously terminates early as it does not finish counting to 99.

Comment: shouldn't it cancel only at the cancellation point only ( at pthread_testcancel() ) call only.

Comment: No, the cancellation is irrelevant in this case. When the main thread exits all child threads will be terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. printf( ) --> write( ), and write( ) is a  inbuilt cancellation point.